# Swagger 2.0 Not working with spring boot when we have Map in requestParams

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using swagger 2.0 version 2.9.2 with spring boot.

When I have `@RequestParam Map<String, String> requestParams` in REST API swagger UI stops working.
When I log `requestParams` it shows `{requestParams={code=1}}` which should be like `{code=1}`

Downgrading to swagger 2.8.0 did not work for me.

I am not expecting `requestParams` attached with my Map of parameters like this `{requestParams={code=1}}`

Comment: Not sure if Map is supported.  https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2241

Comment: @MyTwoCents any hack for this?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

alternative to `Map<String,String> @requestparam` , where you can accept n number of request parameters.

You can get get the request param map by:

```
Map params = request.getParameterMap();
```

(if you add the `HttpServletRequest` request into the function)
and then you can get your parameters from there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Map is supported as per this [link](http://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/224)

You can try these

1. If your Map is not Dynamic, create a DTO and use it instead of Map
2. Try suggestion given in the above link

> You can get get the request param map by:
>
> Map params = request.getParameterMap();
>
> (if you add the HttpServletRequest request into the function)
>
> and then you can get your parameters from there.